# How can I have watir recognize an input tag with a custom class?

Tags: watir

In our application we have some input tags with the following attrbutes:

```
<INPUT class=input-time id=Projects-Projects_Project_0_Task_0_EntryHours_0>
```

I have tried most of the watir input methods but nothing works to recognize this object. Can anyone shed a little light for me?

My watir version is 1.6.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Summary](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Summary) page at Watir wiki links to a few pages with a lot of useful data. Take a look at [How and What](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/How+and+What), [HTML Elements Supported by Watir](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+Elements+Supported+by+Watir) and [Ways Available To Identify HTML Element](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Ways+Available+To+Identify+HTML+Element).

Examples (tested on Mac OS 10.6 with firewatir 1.6.6.rc1):

```
browser.text_field(:id => "Projects-Projects_Project_0_Task_0_EntryHours_0").set "test"
browser.text_field(:id => /Project_0/).set "test"
browser.text_field(:class => "input-time").set "test"
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I'm still pretty new to both Ruby and Watir, so I didn't think about doing it that way!

Answer (score 1):

browser.text_field(:id => /Project_0/).set "test"

If the above code is not working then please try

browser.text_field(:id => /Project_0/).value="test"

Thanks
Raveendran P

Answer (score 1):

browser.text_field(:id => /EntryHours/i).set "test"